# Generating random start and end dates with certain duration in R

Tags: r

How to generate random start and end dates with particular duration in R.

For example
I want to generate a start and end date (as separate variables) of 250 days between a period of **2000-01-01** and current date **2016-04-26**

```
example result for 250 days
start=2014-03-01
end=2014-11-06
```

is there a inbuilt function available in R?

Edit

this is the comment I have given to jasper

> I thought about that method but lets say programme generates starting
>   date as 2016-04-23 but the end date will be 2016-12-29. I want dates
>   between 2000-01-01 and current date 2016-04-26

Answer (score 2):

We can use `seq`

```
sample(seq(as.Date("2014-03-01"), length.out=251, by = "1 day"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just generate a start date somewhere between `2000-01-01` and 250 days before `2016-04-26`, and then add 250 days to the start date?

Comment: I thought about that method but lets say programme generates starting date as 2016-04-23 but the end date will be 2016-12-29. I want dates between 2000-01-01 and current date 2016-04-26

Comment: Then make sure the start date is between `2000-01-01` and `as.Date("2016-04-26") - 250`.  
That way the maximum end date will be `as.Date("2016-04-26") - 250 + 250` = `2016-04-26`.